# @classmethod not invoking my custom descriptor's __get__

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method

I have a decorator called `Special` that turns a function into two versions of itself: one that can be called directly and prefixes the result with `'regular '` and one that can be called with `.special` and prefixes the results with `'special '`:

```
class Special:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return Special(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))

    def special(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'special ' + self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'regular ' + self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works fine with regular methods and static methods - but `.special` does not work with class methods:

```
class Foo:
    @Special
    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

    @staticmethod
    @Special
    def baz():
        return 'baz'

    @classmethod
    @Special
    def qux(cls):
        return 'qux'

assert Foo().bar() == 'regular bar'
assert Foo().bar.special() == 'special bar'

assert Foo.baz() == 'regular baz'
assert Foo.baz.special() == 'special baz'

assert Foo.qux() == 'regular qux'
assert Foo.qux.special() == 'special qux'  # TypeError: qux() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

- `Foo().bar` is invoking `__get__`, which binds the underlying function and passes the bound method to a new instance of `Special` - which is why both `Foo().bar()` and `Foo().bar.special()` work.
- `Foo.baz` is simply returning the original `Special` instance - where both the regular and the special calls are simple.
- `Foo.qux` is binding without calling my `__get__`.

  - The new bound object knows to pass the class as the first argument when being called directly - so `Foo.qux()` works.
  - `Foo.qux.special` is simply calling the `.special` of the underlying function (`classmethod` does not know how to bind it) - so `Foo.qux.special()` is invoking an unbound function, hence the `TypeError`.

Is there any way for `Foo.qux.special` to know it's being called from a `classmethod`? Or some other way around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classmethod` is a descriptor that returns a bound method. It doesn't invoke your `__get__` method in this process because it can't do so without breaking some contracts of the descriptor protocol. (Namely, the fact that `instance` should be an instance, not a class.) So your `__get__` method not being called is completely expected.

So how do you make it work? Well, think about it: You want both `some_instance.bar` and `SomeClass.bar` to return a `Special` instance. In order to achieve that, you simply apply the `@Special` decorator *last*:

```
class Foo:
    @Special
    @staticmethod
    def baz():
        return 'baz'

    @Special
    @classmethod
    def qux(cls):
        return 'qux'
```

This gives you full control over if/when/how the decorated function's descriptor protocol is invoked. Now you just need to remove the `if instance is None:` special case in your `__get__` method, because it prevents classmethods from working correctly. (The reason is that classmethod objects are not callable; you have to invoke the descriptor protocol to turn the classmethod object into a function that can be called.) In other words, the `Special.__get__` method has to unconditionally call the decorated function's `__get__` method, like this:

```
def __get__(self, instance=None, owner=None):
    return Special(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))
```

And now all your assertions will pass.

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer to be able to apply `@classmethod` last (it makes more sense), but I guess that'll have to do...

Comment: This does pass all of his tests, but it will fail on `Foo().qux`. In other words, a special classmethod doesn't act like a classmethod.

Comment: @abarnert Not sure what you mean. `Foo().qux()` returns "regular qux" and `Foo().qux.special()` returns "special qux". What doesn't work?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, got it backward. It works for `Foo().qux`, but [it doesn't work for `Foo.qux()`](https://repl.it/repls/ScaryLavenderCone). See my answer for the explanation of why.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, it's because you didn't remove the `if instance is None: return self` in `__get__`. I guess I should try to clarify that part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `classmethod.__get__` doesn't call the wrapped function's `__get__`—because that's basically the whole point of `@classmethod`. You can look at the pure-Python equivalent to `classmethod` in [the Descriptors HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods), or the actual CPython C source in [`funcobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c#L686), for details, but you'll see that there's really no way around this.

---

Of course if you just `@Special` a `@classmethod`, instead of the other way around, everything will work fine when called on an instance:

```
class Foo:
    @Special
    @classmethod
    def spam(cls):
        return 'spam'

assert Foo().spam() == 'regular spam'
assert Foo().spam.special() == 'special spam'
```

… but now it won't work when called on the class:

```
assert Foo.spam() == 'regular spam'
assert Foo.spam.special() == 'special spam'
```

… because you're trying to call a `classmethod` object, which isn't callable.

---

But this problem, unlike the previous one, is fixable. In fact, the only reason this fails is this part:

```
if instance is None:
    return self
```

When you try to bind a `Special` instance to a class, it just returns `self` instead of binding its wrapped object. Which means it ends up as just a wrapper around a `classmethod` object rather than a wrapper around a bound class method, and of course you can't call a `classmethod` object.

But if you just leave that out, it'll let the underlying `classmethod` bind the same way a normal function does, which does exactly the right thing, and now everything works:

```
class Special:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return Special(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))

    def special(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'special ' + self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'regular ' + self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class Foo:
    @Special
    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

    @Special
    @staticmethod
    def baz():
        return 'baz'

    @Special
    @classmethod
    def qux(cls):
        return 'qux'

assert Foo().bar() == 'regular bar'
assert Foo().bar.special() == 'special bar'

assert Foo.baz() == 'regular baz'
assert Foo.baz.special() == 'special baz'
assert Foo().baz() == 'regular baz'
assert Foo().baz.special() == 'special baz'

assert Foo.qux() == 'regular qux'
assert Foo.qux.special() == 'special qux'
assert Foo().qux() == 'regular qux'
assert Foo().qux.special() == 'special qux'
```

---

Of course this will cause problems with wrapping unbound method objects in Python 2.7, but I think your design already breaks for normal methods in 2.7, and hopefully you only care about 3.x here anyway.